# Unable to update product data via REST API

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api

I send a HTTP PUT request using this url route /rest/V1/products/{SKU}

JSON:

```
{
  "product": {
  "name": "Test title",
  "price": 123
  }
}
```

But nothing is changed on the product.

The response is the same I get when sending a HTTP GET request. So it seems to just ignore that it's an update request.

The product was created by sending a POST request. So POST and GET is working fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the route. Using /V1/products/{SKU} will update a store view, but not All store views. And since Price is a global setting, then nothing is change.

Changing the route to /all/V1/products/{SKU} fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your payload (JSON Body) has to begin with `product`.

Here's a working example:

```
{
  "product": {
    "price": 123.45
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't my JSON begin with "product"??